# Include php files of subfolders at once

Tags: php

In PHP I have a folder with subfolders that contain .php files with either classes or interfaces. There are no further subfolders below that level. 
*Some classes extend other classes which are specified in other folders.*

Structure:

```
MAINFOLDER
- FOLDER1
-- Class1.php
-- Interface1.php
-- Class2.php
- FOLDER2
-- Class3.php
-- Class4.php
-- Interface2.php
- FOLDER3
-- Interface3.php
-- Class5.php
```

I have tried this code:

```
$foldernames = ['FOLDER1','FOLDER2','FOLDER3'];
        foreach ($foldernames as $foldername) {
            foreach (glob('MAINFOLDER/'.$foldername.'/*.php') as $file) {
                include_once $file;
            }
        }
```

The code doesn't work.
Anyone has an idea how to easily include all classes and interfaces at once?

Comment: I have a feeling that you should research on an autoload ... [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: You can also use Composer's autoloader and stick to its conventions.

Answer (score 1):

[spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) is made for that.

It will use the callback given in parameter to include automatically a missing class.

In example :

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className)
{
    $foldernames = ['FOLDER1','FOLDER2','FOLDER3'];
    foreach ($foldernames as $foldername)
    {
        //This example requires, of course, a correct naming of class files
        $file = 'MAINFOLDER/' . $foldername . '/' . $className . '.php';
        if (file_exists($file))
            include $file;
    }
});
```